# CSS - resizing a div affects neighboring divs

Tags: html, css

I have a basic chat site. A chat box in the middle, users hit enter when sending messages. And there's an ajax populated list of the currently logged in users on the right-hand side.

```css
.chat {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.chat .messages {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.present {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -400px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  color: white;  
}

.present .name {
  text-align: center;
}

.name::before {
  content: url("img/blue_dot.png");
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
  <div class="messages"></div>
  <input type="image" id="imgClick" src="css/img/arrow.png">
  <textarea class="entry" placeholder="Enter or arrow to send&#10;Shift+enter for new line"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="indexBoxes">
  <form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="logout" value="Logout">
  </form>
</div>

<div class="present">

</div>
```

Now, since I set the chatbox to be resizable (`resize:both`), when a user tries to change its size, the list of the present users on the right side of the screen `<div class="present"></div>` also moves with it. If the user changes the height - drags it downwards - the list also goes down. I tried to prevent it by giving the list the `position: absolute` to take it out of the flow and then move it back to the right, but it didn't work, still moves with the chat. I also tried not using `margin: 0 auto` to center the box, thinking that it would have any effects, but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well you're attempting to fix the 'div' with the class 'present' in the top right corner, aren't you?
If I've understood well your problem then try to take a look in code snippet I've made for your problem.

```css
.chat {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.chat .messages {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.present {
  float: right;

  margin-right: 50px;
  position: absolute; /*added*/
  right: 0; /*added*/
  top: 0; /*added*/
  color: black;
}

.present .name {
  text-align: center;
}

.name::before {
  content: url("img/blue_dot.png");
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">

  <div class="messages"></div>

  <input type="image" id="imgClick" src="css/img/arrow.png">

  <textarea class="entry" placeholder="Enter or arrow to send&#10;Shift+enter for new line"></textarea>

</div>

<div class="indexBoxes">

  <form action="index.php" method="POST">

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="logout" value="Logout">

  </form>

</div>

<div class="present">User123<br>User321</div>
```

Let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I wanted to prevent the list of the usernames from moving when the chatbox is being resized. Your solution works perfectly. I forgot to set the `top` and `right` to 0 after trying the `position:absolute`. And then remove the margin on the top, since it;s not needed. Thanks a lot, Ray!